# Laravel mail queue wrong mailgun domain

Tags: email, queue, laravel-5.1, swiftmailer, mailgun

I m using Laravel 5.1 and for sending emails I use:

```
Mail::queue(XYZ, compact(ABC), function($message) use ($mailTo)
                {
                    $message->from(XXX, XXX);
                    $message->to(XXX)->subject(XXX);
                });
```

In the services.php I have:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

**and everything works as expected.**

However I had to change my Mailgun domain from *sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org* to *my.domain.com*

and email are not delivered using the new domain unless I use `Mail::send` instead of `Mail::queue`.
I also ran `php artisan queue:restart`, `php artisan cache:clear` and finally I restarted the supervisor on my server but it didn't work.
In my log file I can see that using `Mail::queue`, Guzzle is still using the old domain while contacting Mailgun even if there is not any trace of the old domain in the code anymore.

Any suggestion?!

How can I fix this issue and be able to queue my emails using the new domain?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The queue listening jobs need to be restarted, this is very tricky. Make sure they are correctly stopped and started again.

Comment: thank you @MinaAbadur... can you please go a bit deeper and show me how I can stop those jobs?

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue (and wasted an hour)  -- thank you @MinaAbadir.  Run `php artisan config:clear; php artisan config:cache` then `service supervisor restart`